# Got PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type for oracle collection

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, collections

I want to populate collection with integers but got error

In package spec:

```
type rec_int is record ( i integer );
      
type typ_int is table of rec_int;
```

In package body

```
    function test_randset return pls_integer is
      int_array typ_int;
      ret pls_integer;
    begin
      
      int_array(1) := 1;

      ret := randset(int_array);
    
      return ret;
    end;
```

Error:

```
Error: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
Line: 50
Text: int_array(1) := 1;

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 50
Text: int_array(1) := 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int_array` is a `typ_int`, which is a record with an attribute named `i`, so the assignment should be

```
int_array(1).i := 1;
```

instead of this:

```
int_array(1) := 1;
```

If you defined `type_int` as simply

```
type typ_int is table of integer;
```

then your original assignment would work. I would however give the type a more meaningful name such as `integer_ntt`.

You can test this kind of thing in an anonymous block without having to create a package, for example:

```
declare
    --type rec_int is record(i integer);

    type integer_tt is table of integer;

    function test_randset return pls_integer
    is
        int_array  integer_tt;
        ret        pls_integer;
    begin
        int_array(1) := 1;
        --ret := randset(int_array);
        return ret;
    end;
begin
    null;
end;
```

Comment: It int_array(1).i := 1; works well, thanx a lot!